About to lose 20+ hours of rendering | Blender not responding
so I'm pretty devastated right now. I've been rendering my work for more than 20 HOURS, my PC did not go to sleep mode but my monitor did turn off. I woke the monitor up and saw that Blender is not responding. It should've been done by then. I've been waiting for it to come back. But in the task manager it does not use any CPU and the memory is fixed at 482.2 MB... Is there something I can do? Is there hope to recover my render? I don't have it in me to wait another day to lose it all again.

I’m voting to close this question because there is nothing to answer here that would not be obvious already. If it's frozen, you cannot access any functionality of it, so if you rendered without any output to file or files and/or it did not save any files then you obviously cannot do anything if it's frozen. Nothing can be done about it in a Blender Stack Exchange answer.

You should render animations to separate frames so if something happens you don't loose previously rendered frames. There are also ways to split up still renders into parts if they are particularly long, but that's a separate question.

sure. close it. somebody might have had a solution to maybe a temporary save location or something. That's why I tagged windows. "Obviously" I'm not looking for solutions inside the not working software..........

If you checked Cache Result option in the Output tab, Properties Editor before starting the render, an EXR file of the render (with prefix "cached_" and file name) would be cached in your Temporary Files directory(set in Preferences, temp folder by default (winlogo+r -> paste %temp% to access easily)). Only the last frame is cached. That file is only created for compositing at the end of the render or when you cancel render so it will not be there if render crashed. That's about it for hope.

OK, that might not be so obvious I will retract the close vote.

The things you did make sense:

Wait to see if it recovers
Check hardware utilization to see if it might still be rendering (if you are rendering on GPU, note that Windows Task Manager has options for tracking different aspects of GPU usage and some might show 0% percent, while others might show GPU being used at the same time, sometimes GPU fans not spinning might be a good indication that it's not rendering)

You could also try:

To check if any render files are saved wherever you set the output of your render to be(in the Output tab of Properties editor or with File Output nodes in the Compositor). If you just hit  F12  render is not saved to file using Output tab setting, File Output nodes do save in that case though.

If you checked Cache Result option in the Output tab, Properties Editor before starting the render, an EXR file of the render (with prefix "cached_" and the file name) would be cached in your Temporary Files directory(set in Preferences, temp folder by default (winlogo+r -> paste %temp% to access easily)). Only the last frame is cached. That file is only created for compositing at the end of the render or when you cancel render so it will not be there if render crashed.


If you render animation as image sequence(in image format like EXR or TIF), frames will get saved as they get renderd. Other than that no render data is saved on disk during rendering.

Thank you for your answer. I had to close it before I saw this but I'll come back to this again should I need to.
